# Hinterland's 'exclude regex' doesn't work - using a colon always produces the autocompletion menu

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I've been trying to configure Hinterland for ages, even downgrading to Jupyter 5 to see if that would work. The default settings in Hinter should prevent the autocompletion menu from appearing:

[image: hinterland settings]

In spite of this, I still see the following:

[image]

I've tried various other obvious configurations, including stripping out parts from the default include_regexp field, but I've had no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer in case anyone else ever has this issue. I enabled the hinterland extensions through anaconda prompt after entering the regex I wanted in the interface. This seemed to make the regex actually work in the notebook.

Specifically I used the command `jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland`.